# natural way of thinking this logarithm inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I know that this inequality hold for $x\geq0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\ln(x+n)<nx+n$$
in fact, when $x=0$, for all $n$, $\ln(n)<n$

if $x>0$, 
$$\frac{d}{dx}[\ln(x+n)]=\frac{1}{x+n}\qquad \frac{d}{dx}[nx+n]=n $$
of course,
$$\frac{d}{dx}[\ln(x+n)]<\frac{d}{dx}[nx+n]\qquad; x>0 \quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$

So, $nx+n$ rise (or increase it value) faster than $\ln(x+n)$ and the inequality is satisfied for $x=0$, so we conclude that $\ln(x+n)<nx+n$

**My cuestion.** Is there a natural way to get that first inequality? because I can prove $\ln(x+n)<nx+n$, but I can't imagine a natural way to construct it. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the even stronger inequality $\ln ( x + n )\lt x + n $. For $n\ge1$, the claim follows.

Comment: Drawing the graph $f(x)=ln(x)$ easily shows that $ln(x)<x$ holds for every real $x>0$

Comment: This even stronger inequality holds: $\ln(x)\le x-1$ (with equality iff $x=1$), which can be derived from $e^x\ge x+1$ (my favorite definition of $e$).

Comment: yeah is really simple, I was blocked. Thanks you a lot!